# How to load additional runtime dependencies in sbt launcher based application

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have been experimenting with an [sbt launcher](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Launcher/GettingStarted.html) and actor based application that needs to be able access dependencies that were not known at compile time.
The properties file you pass to the sbt launcher can define addition "resources", which are plain jar files, however what I really want is to specify additional dependencies in the launcher properties file. Is there any way to do that, so that the additional dependencies are resolved at runtime?

If it doesn't work with sbt launcher, I suppose an alternative would be to use OSGI, however that would probably involve a lot of work making osgi bundles for all the other dependencies that don't have them.